# Extracting data from a json file into a csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I am new to dealing with json files and I am hoping for some help. 
Here is a part of the json file (since it would be way too much for me to post it all) that I am dealing with

```
[{"id":804,"name":{"english":"Naganadel","japanese":"\u30a2\u30fc\u30b4\u30e8\u30f3"},"type":["Poison","Dragon"],"base":{"HP":73,"Attack":73,"Defense":73,"Sp. Attack":127,"Sp. Defense":73,"Speed":121}},{"id":805,"name":{"english":"Stakataka","japanese":"\u30c4\u30f3\u30c7\u30c4\u30f3\u30c7"},"type":["Rock","Steel"],"base":{"HP":61,"Attack":131,"Defense":211,"Sp. Attack":53,"Sp. Defense":101,"Speed":13}},{"id":806,"name":{"english":"Blacephalon","japanese":"\u30ba\u30ac\u30c9\u30fc\u30f3"},"type":["Fire","Ghost"],"base":{"HP":53,"Attack":127,"Defense":53,"Sp. Attack":151,"Sp. Defense":79,"Speed":107}},{"id":807,"name":{"english":"Zeraora","japanese":"\u30bc\u30e9\u30aa\u30e9"},"type":["Electric"],"base":{"HP":88,"Attack":112,"Defense":75,"Sp. Attack":102,"Sp. Defense":80,"Speed":143}},{"id":808,"name":{"english":"Meltan","japanese":"\u30e1\u30eb\u30bf\u30f3"},"type":["Steel"],"base":{"HP":46,"Attack":65,"Defense":65,"Sp. Attack":55,"Sp. Defense":35,"Speed":34}},{"id":809,"name":{"english":"Melmetal","japanese":"\u30e1\u30eb\u30e1\u30bf\u30eb"},"type":["Steel"],"base":{"HP":135,"Attack":143,"Defense":143,"Sp. Attack":80,"Sp. Defense":65,"Speed":34}}]
```

I am attempting to take the id, name, type, base, hp, attack, defense, and speed of each pokemon. I attached what I currently have which include my attempting to take the id and print it.

When I run this file I get list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

```
import json

def main():

    f = open('pokedex.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    #print data
    id_poke = data['_embedded']['id_poke']
    id_info = []
    for i in id_poke:
        id_poke.append(i['id'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: JSON is not line-based. You need to include enough json to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you I understand this I just did not want to include the whole file. I include a bit more information from the JSON file. Thank you for you edit

Comment: At a glance it appears to be enough of the JSON to debug your code, but perhaps not entirely. Where is `_embedded` and `id_poke` in your JSON?

Comment: Most likely the issue here is `data['_embedded']` is a list, but you are treating it as a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the json sample you included in your question: It starts with a `[`, meaning it is a *list*, not a dictionary. When you assign this object to the variable `data` and then try to index into this list with the (string) key `_embedded`, you get the error you saw.

I don't know how you expected this to work since your json file has neither `_embedded` nor `id_poke` as keys, but to get you started, here's how to print out the numeric id and English name of each object; you can take it from there.

```
for poke in data:   # magic iteration over a list: data[0], data[1] etc.
    print(poke["id"], poke["name"]["english"])
```

Answer (score -3):

Declare

```
id_poke = data['_embedded']['id_poke']
```

As str()